# Randomizing a list using Rand in perl

Tags: perl, cgi

Hi i currently am using the List::Util shuffle to randomize a array with CGI however I want to modify the code to use rand instead

here is my code

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
use List::Util qw(shuffle);
@haikuone = ('behind', 'the', 'red', 'barn');
@haikutwo = ('prairie', 'grasses', 'reclaiming'); 
@haikuthree = ('the', 'basketball', 'court');

@randomize1 = shuffle(@haikuone);
@randomize2 = shuffle(@haikutwo);
@randomize3 = shuffle(@haikuthree);

print "<html>\n";
print "<head><title>Haiku_Random</title></head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "<pre>\n";
print "RANDOM HAIKU (DISCLAIMER: NONSENSE MAY OCCUR)\n";

print "@randomize1\n";

print "@randomize2\n";

print "@randomize3\n";
```

How would i modify this code to use rand instead of List::Util

I dont think its much but a novice here

I'm trying to get this working

```
$haikuone = ('behind', 'the', 'red', 'barn');
$haikutwo = ('prairie', 'grasses', 'reclaiming'); 
$haikuthree = ('the', 'basketball', 'court');

@random1 = $line1[rand @haikuone];
@random2 = $line2[rand @haikutwo];
@random3 = $line3[rand @haikuthree];
print "RANDOM HAIKU (DISCLAIMER: NONSENSE MAY OCCUR)\n";
print "$line1\n";
```

Now when i do this

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/perl

 @haikuone = ('behind', 'the', 'red', 'barn');
 @haikutwo = ('prairie', 'grasses', 'reclaiming'); 
 @haikuthree = ('the', 'basketball', 'court');

 @random1 = $line1[rand @haikuone];
 @random2 = $line2[rand @haikutwo];
 @random3 = $line3[rand @haikuthree];
 print "RANDOM HAIKU (DISCLAIMER: NONSENSE MAY OCCUR)\n";
 print "@haikuone\n";
```

It will print haikuone but it wont randomize it

Comment: what is wrong with `List::Util`?

Comment: Worst case scenario, copy and paste what List::Util does. One thing I've picked up over the years : there are a lot of ways to get list shuffling wrong. You should always use an existing solution that's widely considered to be good.

Comment: see post update above

Comment: "Worst case scenario, copy and paste what List::Util does" - List::Util::shuffle() is implemented in XS. So copying that code might not be all that simple :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sub fisher_yates_shuffle {
    my $deck = shift;  # $deck is a reference to an array
    return unless @$deck; # must not be empty!

    my $i = @$deck;
    while (--$i) {
        my $j = int rand ($i+1);
        @$deck[$i,$j] = @$deck[$j,$i];
    }
}

my @randomize1 = @haikuone;
fisher_yates_shuffle(\@randomize1);
print "@randomize1\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! You have the following code, but don't have any arrays named `@haikuone`, `@haikutwo`, `@haikuthree`, `@line1`, `@line2` or `@line3`.

```
@random1 = $line1[rand @haikuone];
@random2 = $line2[rand @haikutwo];
@random3 = $line3[rand @haikuthree];
```

It's also really weird that use three arrays with one element each.

Comment: OK now when i do this it doesnt randomize. View changed code above

Comment: You did not "do this". I shall repeat: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! I updated the post with three more errors it would have told you about!

Comment: i do have arrays LOOK above

Comment: I never said you didn't have arrays. Start by using `use strict; use warnings;`. It'll show you all the variables you're using without declaring, which is directly relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi i currently am using the List::Util shuffle to randomize a array
>   with CGI

This makes sense. `List::Util::shuffle()` is the best way to shuffle a list in Perl - whether or not you're writing a CGI program.

> however I want to modify the code to use rand instead

This doesn't make sense. `rand()` doesn't shuffle a list. It just generates a random number.

It's a good idea to use `rand()` to extract a single random element from an array.

```
my $random_element = @array[rand @array];
```

But that's not what you're trying to do.

If you really want to use `rand()` then you need to incorporate its use in a function. There's a good function given in the Perl FAQ (in the answer to the question - ["How do I shuffle an array randomly?"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-shuffle-an-array-randomly%3f) - so perhaps you should have taken a look at the FAQ before asking here) which looks like this:

```
sub fisher_yates_shuffle {
    my $deck = shift;  # $deck is a reference to an array
    return unless @$deck; # must not be empty!
    my $i = @$deck;
    while (--$i) {
        my $j = int rand ($i+1);
        @$deck[$i,$j] = @$deck[$j,$i];
    }
}
```

But note that this is implemented in Perl. The `shuffle()` function in List::Util is written in C, so it's going to be faster.

So, all in all, there's really no good reason for not using `List::Util::shuffle()`.